# If I use a function as a condition in a while loop, will it run the whole function or just check if the return is desired

Tags: python, function

If I do

```
def main():
    while foo() != False:
      pass
    #code outside while loop
```

When I run the program, literally nothing happens. foo is defined before main but calls functions defined after main
will the whole of foo() be executed (including asking for inputs, saving local variables etc) until the return value is False, or will it skip all of that and only search for return values?

foo is this

```
def mainFunc():
  num1Str = input(print("Please enter your first number: "))
  if(endCheck(num1Str)):
    return False
  while (num1Str.isdigit() == False):
    num1Str = input(print("Error. Please enter a valid integer."))
  num1Int = int(num1Str)

  op = input(print("What is your operator? (chose from + - x /)"))
  if(endCheck(num1Str)):
    return False
  while (opCheck(op)):
    op = input(print("Error. Please enter a valid operator."))

  num2Str = input(print("Please enter your second number: "))
  if(endCheck(num1Str)):
    return False
  while (num2Str.isdigit() == False):
    num2Str = input(print("Error. Please enter a valid integer."))
  num2Int = int(num2Str)

  ans = calculate(num1Int, op, num2Int)
  if (ans):
    return False

  print("Your answer is" + str(ans))
  global counter
  counter += 1
```

Comment: It depends what is in `foo()`. Can you update your question with an example of what is in `foo()`?

Comment: How can it check the return value without running the function?

Comment: @quamrana It doesn't depend on what's in `foo()`.

Comment: @Barmar: I was thinking of `functools.cache`

Comment: i would think the very first line
```num1Str = input(print("Please enter your first number: "))```
would defo run

Comment: Do you actually call `main()`?

Comment: wait that is a thing

Comment: Yes. Sometimes its so hard to get programmers to put code into functions and here you are making neat functions, but you end up never calling any.

Comment: omg im dumb tysm i literally had to call main

Answer (score 0):

`foo()` will be called, and it will run to completion. Whether *all* of it is executed will depend on the conditional statements in the function. If it executes a `return` statement it will stop there.

> will it skip all of that and only search for return values?

That doesn't make sense. The `return` statements execute depending on the results of previous statements. If it skipped all that, how would it know what the return values would be?

I suppose you could have a function whose `return` statements always return the same thing, so the `if` condition will always be the same. But the rest of the code can have side effects (printing messages, asking for input, writing to files, etc.), and these side effects are required to take place before the value can be used. There are some "lazy" languages that don't have such requirements, but Python is not one of them.

The position of the function definitions with respect to the `main()` definition is not relevant. What matters is whether the functions are defined before you *call* the `main()` function.

If you're not even seeing the first prompt, the only explanation could be that you're never calling the `main()` function in the first place. Unlike C and C++, `main()` is not executed automatically. Python is a scripting language, so it executes the top-level code of the file; if you have a `main()` function, you must call it explicitly.

Comment: Thank you ye that was the problem I didn't call main

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing the main() call at the end of your code. As @Barmar said above, you have to explicitly call your main function, unlike Java and C.

Coming into Python from Java and C myself, I made this dumb error often too...

Hope this fixes it!

Also, I don't know if this is a big issue, but personally, I think it's good practice to explicitly return true in your foo() functions along with the false returns you have already!

Comment: Yup that was it thanks! Still a lot more bugs to go including this 'none' output I have faced but the reason it wasnt running was infact bcus I didn't call main() lol

Comment: Don't use print in your input! Input takes in a string param to print out anyway!